# $ signs prevent code blocks from ending on MathJax-enabled SE sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown-rendering, mathjax

It looks like on StackExchange sites that have MathJax enabled, certain placements of `$` characters inside code blocks can prevent the code block from ending.

Here's an [example post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1140/12) where this has happened.  Please see the longest code block: the middle should be text, but it is rendered as code.

I managed to come up with a minimal example.  The following markdown,

```
    $ this is code

this is text

$
```

renders like this:

```
$ this is code

this is text

$
```

(i.e. the middle text line appears as code).

[image: example image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [improved Markdown/LaTeX separator](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3955/3) now handles this case. I've made an edit to the post to force rebuilding the HTML – and remove the sentence noting that something is broken :) – and it now looks as expected.

Your minimal example now works correctly as well.

Comment: There's another note about the broken rendering at the beginning of the post.  I removed that one as well.  Thanks! :-)

Comment: There are some problems again with $ signs and code blocks.  Try this on a MathJax enabled site: http://pastebin.com/hpBfYs79  The second code line will have extra indentation.  Again, this comes up on Mathematica.SE in practice, because Mathematica tends to use $ signs (for example, in [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15966/how-to-make-this-code-threadsafe), if the second, empty, line of the code block is removed.)